# Clonezilla Fails to clone 16.04 /16.10

Tags: clone, clonezilla

Clonezilla 2.4.7-8-i686 failed to (full disk) clone:

Laptop: SSD with 16.04
Desktop: Dual-boot Win7+16.10.  3 attempts: freezes each time

Clonezilla has been my go-to for Windows imaging.  Has anyone had success with imaging Ubuntu with Clonezilla or is it unsuitable for this task?  Any lesson-learned (relevant facts) are appreciated

[image]

Comment: There's always `dd`...

Comment: How are you trying to clone?  Full disk, or partition-by-partition?

Comment: Good question: full disk

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you have installed the Ubuntu OS by choosing a supported file system like `ext4`, no, this is most probably not a problem with Clonezilla. I am using it regularly to make a backup image of my Linux operating systems, including Ubuntu. Some approaches to solve your issues :

- Please use the latest stable 64-bit version 2.4.9-17 of Clonezilla, you can download it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/clonezilla_live_stable/2.4.9-17/).
- Make sure that the Windows partition is not in use (disable hibernation mode in Windows).
- In case it still freezes, use the partition cloning option ... backup each partition separately.

How to backup the single partitions you can see in this presentation -> [clonezilla-save-partitions](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13-GCZyxH51pWD-aMzmD-QNpDr7U28ZqTmEB-Iy3wizM/edit#slide=id.p)
Note : I made the presentation some time ago, a few new steps such as the possibility to choose a sub folder of the backup destination directory have been added, but the main part is still valid.

**Update addressing the bitmap error message as shown in the screenshot you have added :**

It is possible that you have a problem with the file system on a partition of the disk. Download [GParted](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.27.0-1/), create a bootable media and check the disks and partitions, alternatively you can use the Ubuntu installation media, GParted is included there. If you see something suspicious here run `fsck`, open a terminal and execute : `sudo fsck.ext4 /dev/sdXY` (X = disk | Y = partition). When this does not solve the problem, format the partition with GParted and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Before cloning I shutdown windows: does this ensure that the Windows partition is not in use.  Thank you for confirming that you are effectively using Clonezilla

Comment: @gatorback : Did you disable hibernation by opening command prompt as administrator and executing : powercfg /h off ? I have to add that cloning Ubuntu as well as red hat based distros works on 3 different machines in my case - one PC has an EFI based BIOS and two of them have a legacy (MBR) based BIOS. :)

Comment: I just tried 'powercfg /h off' and posted the photo of the outcome.  Are any of your machines dual boot?  All my boxes use BIOS

Comment: @gatorback : Two of my machines are having a dual boot setup - the EFI based machine fedora 24 and Ubuntu 16.10, the BIOS based machine RHEL Server 7.3 and Ubuntu Server 16.10 ... to reproduce your issue, I created a complete disk image with Clonezilla 2.4.9-17 - it went through without any problem. :) Now to the photo you posted ... it looks like you have a problem with the block sizes on your disk. You could check whether a reinstallation of Ubuntu 16.10 solves it, maybe you have a faulty installation. :)